# Drive letter mapping for a Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning redirection

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, driver

I'm not sure what would be the right approach in this situation. I need to map Windows drive letter to a custom Web DAV connected server. Or in other words, when a user goes to My Computer, then, say, goes to drive Z: they should see files and folders from that Web DAV server.

My preferred programming language is C/C++/MFC.

Is my only option a kernel mode device driver?

Comment: I thought Windows had native DAV support...

Comment: @Deanna: Windows built-in DAV seems be tying it in to Office and is quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  What you are asking for can be accomplished by creating a [Shell Namespace Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521728.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you. This makes me breathe easy. So now all I have left to do is find a C++ code sample on how to do it...

Comment: Shell Namespace Extensions can be written in any language that supports the creation of COM objects. C++, Delphi, VB, .NET, just to name a few.

Comment: What's the one closest to C++ -- ATL extension. I'm just trying to get an example to get me started?